# How can I disable the "Get a better username on YouTube" prompt?

Tags: youtube

YouTube constantly prompts me to update to use a real name (and thus attach a Google+ account to my email address).  I've selected the option to continue using my old username only, but it doesn't matter — it just prompts me again later over and over.  Is there any way to permanently disable this, or a userscript to prevent it from popping up?  I use Chrome if it matters.

Comment: Do you use multiple computers?  Do you block or wipe out your cookies?   Perhaps the nag disable is stored in a cookie or something like that?

Comment: @Zoredache That occurred to me too.  I'm prety sure it's popped up on the same computer twice without wiping cookies but I will pay more attention.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same prompt to get a better username from YouTube. I followed the prompt, and told YouTube that I wanted to keep my existing YouTube username. This was a one-shot deal for me. I haven't received the same prompt from YouTube again.

So why doesn't this work for you? I was already logged in to YouTube at the time I received the prompt. Maybe YouTube doesn't save your settings unless you are logged in when you input them.

The language used in the steps that follow the YouTube prompt is tricky, and may even be confusing to some people. I strongly advise you to read everything very carefully before you click on anything.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts, but I've definitely taken the right steps while logged in ... I did select the option to use different names for YouTube and Google-in-general since I want to keep my YT username separate from my Gmail name.  I've gone through the steps one more time, I'll see if it sticks.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this userscript:

http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/153375

> Removes the pop-up from Youtube that tells you to "Get a better name on YouTube" by using your Google+ username instead.

[image]